# npm install is giving an error after installing node js and visual studio community

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\ZTM\simplefolio>

---

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\HP\Desktop\ZTM\simplefolio\node_modules\lmdb-store
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-12-11T10_40_35_068Z-debug-0.log

I have uninstalled and reinstalled node.js then installed Visual studio community 2022 and I am still facing this error , what can be done?